# The default django `User` model generating huge number of queries, when working with views in DRF?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build an endpoint for the default `User` model, which we have in django, which being imported from `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`,
This is my serializer:-

```py
class SuperUserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username',
            'groups',
            'user_permissions',
            'organization_users',
        )
```

and the views goes as this:-

```py
class UserDetailView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SuperUserDetailSerializer
```

with the above codes, the number of queries which being hit are `216-219`, which is due to the field `user_permissions`, I checked the `User` model, but it doesn't contains any field as `user_permissions`, but in the response, I get this field, and also in the html form field the permissions are populated(DRF Browsable page). I am trying to implement `prefetch_related` or `select_related` for the `user_permissions` field, but I am not able to reduce the the number of query, (It is hitting the database each time for getting all the permissions).

This is what I am trying to do but not able to achieve it:-

`queryset = User.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('user_permissions', queryset = Permission.obects.select_related('content_type')))`...I am not sure where I am doing the mistake.

Comment: Why do you have to serialize or deserialize user permissions ?

Comment: I would like to assign and unassign user permission with the API endpoint.

Comment: `django.contrib.auth.models.Permission` model have `ContentType` field that can be tricky to serialize. What about serializing `django.contrib.auth.models.Group` which has only two fields that are name and the permissions. So you can create as many groups as you want assign permissions manually and serialize only group name.